# Custom Flash Video Player convert experience to HTML5?

Tags: ios, html, flash, video, mobile

I have a custom built flash (.swf) video player that is connected to an api where videos are tagged so users can bookmark elements of the video and these bookmarks have links to external sites.  Is there anyway to convert the flash player to function as it was designed to HTML5 so it is compatible across all devices?  I know this is a long shot, but the company that designed this player designed it for the web and has a native app that mobile users must download to view the tagged up video.  Obviously this situation is less than ideal.  Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will have to re-build it, there are no Flash to HTML5 converts with this capacity to my knowledge.

Comment: Thank you.  I will look into this.  Cool video player, I will dig deeper.